# Same values are repeated in sqlite database query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having three tables such as trade,advance and loans i have to create a list showing the sum of trade,loan as well as advance for each month suppose if a month doesn't have trade means it should display it as zero but instead of displaying the value as zero it shows the summed value of the previous months in the next month also can any one tell me where i am wrong in this query since i have very little knowledge in sqlite.

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%Y', tradedate) as 'month', 
   (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(tradebalanceamount),0 ) 
       FROM farmertradelabel 
       WHERE farmertradelabel.mobileno = ' 9486032141 '  
       ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate) DESC) AS tradeamount,
  (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(advanceamount),0)  
       FROM advancelabel 
       WHERE advancelabel.mobileno = '9486032141'  
       ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) DESC) AS advanceamount,
  (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(loantotalamount),0) 
      FROM loanlabel 
      WHERE loanlabel.mobileno = '9486032141' 
      ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) DESC) AS loanamount   
FROM farmertradelabel
```

Table Structure:

Trade table:

```
 String CREATE_FARMERTRADE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + FARMERTRADE_LABELS + "("
            + TRADE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + TRADE_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_MOBNO + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_COCONUTTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_TOTALCOCONUT + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_COCONUTCOST + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_TOTALAMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_AMOUNTPAID + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_BALANCEAMT + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FARMERTRADE_TABLE);
```

Advance Table:

```
String CREATE_ADVANCE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ADVANCE_LABELS + "("
            + ADVANCE_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + ADVANCE_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_USERTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_MOBNO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + ADVANCE_AMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_REASON + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ADVANCE_TABLE);
```

Loan Table:

```
 String CREATE_LOAN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + LOAN_LABELS + "("
            + LOAN_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + LOAN_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_USERTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_MOBNO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + LOAN_AMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_INTEREST + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_PERIOD + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_DUEDATE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_REASON + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_TOTALAMOUNT + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOAN_TABLE);
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: reformatted sql request for better readability

Comment: Some of your values are just SUMs of a table They do not have any date checks on them, based on the month you are checking for. So every row SUMs the same thing

Comment: Post the tables  structure in order to help you

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Comment: @Doomsknight I want to filter the data's month wise if a particular month doesn't have value then it should display 0 else it should show the current month value but the values gets repeated for the next month also so how i can change it can you please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following works for the `advancedamount` and `loanamount` fields.
Basically, you need to check the month is the month of the current row, and SUM it, else exclude it. Using a where clause.

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%Y', tradedate) as 'month', 
   (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(FTL.tradebalanceamount),0 ) 
       FROM farmertradelabel as FTL 
       WHERE FTL.mobileno = '9486032141'  AND strftime('%m-%Y', FTL.tradedate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
       ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', FTL.tradedate) DESC) AS tradeamount,
  (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(advanceamount),0)  
       FROM advancelabel 
       WHERE advancelabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
       ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) DESC) AS advanceamount,
  (SELECT IFNULL (SUM(loantotalamount),0) 
      FROM loanlabel 
      WHERE loanlabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
      ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) DESC) AS loanamount   
FROM farmertradelabel
```

The `tradeamount` requires you to go one step further and add Alias' to the table, as you are using the same table name twice.

Modified example above to include Alias'

Comment: @RameshR Sorry that is a typo, should be `strftime`

Comment: how could i get the min and max dates of these three tables and show the min and max dates

Comment: @RameshR an example: `MIN(loanlabel.loandate)`  or `MAX(loanlabel.loandate)` [A nice Tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)

Comment: everything works fine but only the trade amount gets repeated rest of them are fine

Comment: @RameshR Yes, for tradeamount you need to implement alias' and then do a date check, as per instructions/examples above. Ive modified the example to demonstrate this

Comment: it works fine @DoomsKnight can u suggest me some sites or book to learn the sql in depth

Comment: @RameshR , Glad to hear its working. Yes just read here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp . w3 schools is great. Just press Next to go through each section, or use the navigation on the left. It will teach you all the basics.

Comment: there is  a problem when i add a loan for a different date when i didn't do trade the data is not displayed for that loan can you tell me why it happens like that

Comment: @RameshR It happens because your list of dates is built from your `farmertradelabel` table. Which then populates data from those dates. You should ask another stackoverflow question to address the new issue.

Comment: check this question @DoomsKnight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131227/data-gets-populated-from-a-particular-tables-date-instead-of-all-table-in-sqlit

Comment: can you help me in the question which i have posted

Comment: @RameshR Ive put a small bounty on it, to draw attention :) Busy at the moment