# Data gets populated from a particular table's date instead of all table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have three table namely trade, advance, and loan in which when I entered some values in loan it doesn't get displayed until I enter some values in trade for that particular date/month.

So can anyone tell me how I can overcome this issue?

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%Y', tradedate) as 'month', 
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(FTL.tradebalanceamount),0 ) 
   FROM farmertradelabel as FTL 
   WHERE FTL.mobileno = '9486032141'  AND strftime('%m-%Y', FTL.tradedate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
   ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', FTL.tradedate) DESC) AS tradeamount,
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(advanceamount),0)  
   FROM advancelabel 
   WHERE advancelabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
   ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) DESC) AS advanceamount,
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(loantotalamount),0) 
  FROM loanlabel 
  WHERE loanlabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) = strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate)
  ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) DESC) AS loanamount   
FROM farmertradelabel
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't get displayed". Can you post an example of the faulty output and the output you expect?

Comment: His sums are linked to the dates in trade table. He could write union and do the above 3 times. But must be a cleaner solution. The other thing is maybe union the from bit and create a virtual table

Comment: @Ahmed Ghonim If the trade table doens't have any records for this month and if the loan table or the advance table has records for this months means it doens't gets displayed.My expected output is even if any of these three tables has a record for this month and rest of the tables doesn't have then it should display that record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below.

What I have done is created a virtual table, containing unique months. To which there is info in one of the 3 tables for that month. Then the sums are bound to that month.

I have also removed the `ORDER BY` in the `SUM` clauses, as they don't change the result. Your `IFNULL` could also be changed, depending on how you expect it to work.

This method saves you writing out 3 lots of SUMs for each 3 fields (9 SUMs). If there are any typos, please fix accordingly.

NOTE that `month` is a keyword, in some SQL. So ideally, a better column name should be used.

```
SELECT month, 
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(FTL.tradebalanceamount),0 ) 
   FROM farmertradelabel as FTL 
   WHERE FTL.mobileno = '9486032141'  AND strftime('%m-%Y', FTL.tradedate) = month) AS tradeamount,
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(advanceamount),0)  
   FROM advancelabel 
   WHERE advancelabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', advancelabel.advancedate) = month) AS advanceamount,
(SELECT IFNULL (SUM(loantotalamount),0) 
  FROM loanlabel 
  WHERE loanlabel.mobileno = '9486032141' AND strftime('%m-%Y', loanlabel.loandate) = month) AS loanamount   

FROM
 (SELECT strftime('%m-%Y', tradedate) as 'month' FROM farmertradelabel
 UNION 
   SELECT  strftime('%m-%Y', advancedate) as 'month' FROM advancelabel
 UNION 
   SELECT strftime('%m-%Y', loandate) as 'month' FROM loanlabel
 ) as dateTable
```